# How do I deal with warnings generated by Boost.Spirit?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

I have recently installed boost, and i was experimenting with the Spirit library.  I compiled a simple example which parses a comma-seperated list of numbers and adds them together.  The program compiled, but my compiler (VS 2013) issued a rediculous amount of warnings.  Have a look at the source:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

using qi::double_;
using qi::_1;
using ascii::space;
using phoenix::ref;

template <typename Iterator>
bool adder(Iterator first, Iterator last, double& n)
{
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last,

        //  Begin grammar
        (
            double_[ref(n) = _1] >> *(',' >> double_[ref(n) += _1])
        )
        ,
        //  End grammar

        space);

    if (first != last) // fail if we did not get a full match
        return false;
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    double result;
    if (!adder(str.begin(), str.end(), result))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid syntax." << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "The result is " << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This generated 309 lines of warnings!  They all looked similar to this:

```
c:\boost\boost/spirit/home/support/terminal.hpp(264) : warning C4348: 'boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::lit>::result_helper' : redefinition of default parameter : parameter 3
        c:\boost\boost/spirit/home/support/terminal.hpp(270) : see declaration of 'boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::lit>::result_helper'
        c:\boost\boost/spirit/home/support/common_terminals.hpp(142) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::lit>' being compiled
```

The program compiled fine and did what I thought it would do, but I'm wondering how to manage all of these warnings without silencing the useful ones.  Is there a way to disable warnings originating from boost, but to preserve the warnings generated by my code?  Spirit is a fairly popular library, so I know that there's some way to deal with it.

Answer (score 6):

With VC++ you need to wrap your Boost includes in a few pragmas:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4348)
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#pragma warning(pop)

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// ...
```

Add to the `disable` list as needed, space delimited ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)).

Other compilers typically allow you to tag specified include paths as 'system' paths, and all warnings from headers in system paths are suppressed. For GCC and Clang in particular, use `-isystem` rather than `-I` ([docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html)).

Comment: Why don't they put these pragmas into boost itself? (#ifdef if necessary but the whole point of pragma was you don't have to) I see a million of these while compiling boost 1.60.0 via b2 with VC++ 2015, and it makes the installation process a mess.

Comment: @WarrenP : That's extremely impractical, given that compiler diagnostics (for any compiler, not just VC++) change every compiler release, and Boost supports over a dozen compilers. The amount of work involved is huge. In 2010 Boost did have a community-wide "warning cleanup drive" that lasted a few months and fixed thousands of warnings, but keeping on top of it as development goes on is a nearly insurmountable problem.

Comment: I cleaned them up locally in about 5 minutes.  Maybe I'll send the brilliant Haxxors at Boost a pull request. I am unaware of any compiler that barfs on a non-understood pragma warn directive.

Comment: @WarrenP : Silencing warnings is not "cleaning" anything up, it's only shutting something up; if there's to be a real fix, then fix what's causing the warnings in the first place. This way, you'll help all compilers instead of just the version of the compiler that you happen to be using right now. `#pragma warning` is code pollution to work around code you _can't_ fix; Boost is open-source, so just actually fix it.

Comment: For that I guess I'd need to  `understand_problem<What<The,Heck>::Is_Going<On,InThere>>` which I don't.  It's a curious warning though and I think I'll try to figure out what the heck it really means.

Comment: @WarrenP : Out of curiosity, which warning?

Comment: C4348 :  'boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::lit>::result_helper' : redefinition of default parameter : parameter 3  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxef26tw.aspx

Comment: It's almost like there ought to be some header guards and there aren't, and so we get this warning.

Comment: @WarrenP : Ah, Spirit.Classic code then. I can't say I'm overly surprised – that is a **long**-dead code base, deprecated and retained only for backwards compatibility (probably only for Boost.Serialization at this point really). (Rather nasty code, too: _so_ much type erasure...) Well, I have to give that one to you – not at all worth fixing, so a perfect candidate for suppression pragmas. :-P

Comment: Yeah, I don't even use it. My use-case is "As a developer I want to run b2 and not see a billion lines of noise".